# Is it possible to change the radio button icon in an android radio button group

Tags: android, radio-button

I am wanting to allow the user of my android application the ability to set some parameters.  The radio button is ideal for this situation.  However, I don't like the radio buttons are rendered.

Is it possible to change the radio button icon?  For example, is it possible to create a custom layout for each row and in that layout reference my own icon and change the font et al.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Yes that's possible you have to define your own style for radio buttons, at res/values/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
   <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButton</item>
</style>
<style name="RadioButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
   <item name="android:button">@drawable/radio</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

'radio' here should be a stateful drawable, radio.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_hover" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_normal" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_active" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_active" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_hover" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_normal_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_normal" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_hover" />
    </selector>
```

Then just apply the Custom theme either to whole app or to activities of your choice.

For more info about themes and styles look at http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/ that is good guide.

Comment: You can also just set the android:button property on the radio button itself, rather than defining a separate custom style for it.

Comment: True, but that's not too good practice, since you usually have more then just one radio button.

Comment: @KonstantinBurov what if i'm using a 9 patch image?

Comment: @KonstantinBurov Unless you're adding Buttons programmatically, in which case it's great :)

Comment: For support theme might want to use
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButton</item>
<item name="radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButton</item>
</style>

Answer (score 32):

You can put custom image in radiobutton like normal button.
for that create one XML file in drawable folder 
e.g

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sub_screens_aus_hl" 
    android:state_pressed="true"/>  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sub_screens_aus" 
    android:state_checked="true"/>  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sub_screens_aus" 
    android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sub_screens_aus_dis" />  
</selector>
```

Here you can use 3 different images for radiobutton

and use this file to RadioButton like:

```
android:button="@drawable/aus"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 20):

The easier way to only change the radio button is simply set selector for drawable right

```
<RadioButton
    ...
    android:button="@null"
    android:checked="false"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/radio_button_selector" />
```

And the selector is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_checked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_unchecked" android:state_checked="false" /></selector>
```

That's all

Comment: Best solution, for my case I also changed 'drawableRight' to 'button' and added some padding to the selector xml

Comment: This is best solution . I was used this manner and it works fine.But after migrating to andoidx android:button="@null" does not work and we see two radio button icon for every item ! .

Answer (score 4):

yes....`
from Xml

```
android:button="@drawable/yourdrawable"
```

and from Java

```
myRadioButton.setButtonDrawable(resourceId or Drawable);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Here's probably a quick approach,

[image]

With two icons shown above, you shall have a `RadioGroup` something like this

[image]

- change the `RadioGroup`'s orientation to horizontal
- for each `RadioButton`'s Properties, try giving the icon for `Button`
  under `CompoundButton`,
- adjust the Padding and size,
- and set the Background attribute when checked.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do it programmatically,

```
checkBoxOrRadioButton.setButtonDrawable(null);
checkBoxOrRadioButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.resource_name);
```