# Android : Button and left border in Radio Button

Tags: android, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

[image]

Is there any way to give Space between radio Circle and left border. I'm tried to give margin but it's not working ,I also try to give padding but it increase space between text and button.

Radio xml Code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/chkIos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_12sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/option_layout"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/_12sdp"
                android:text="1211asd3"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/option_layout"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_42sdp"
                android:padding="@dimen/_12sdp"
                android:text="RadioButton2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_42sdp" />


            <!--<TextView-->
            <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know how it can be Done?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/54394333/7666442

Comment: Hi @NileshRathod in your answer he is not given any drawable to button that's why there is space between button and left margin ...
Thank you but it's not solve the problem

Comment: You need to add padding to your icon manually in your source images, default icons have some padding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pasting your images directly to drawable folders, Try importing them from

```
File -> new -> Image Asset
```

It will show you following dialog where you need to select **Icon type** as **Actionbar and Tab Icons** and add padding using the padding control. Default icons have some padding in them try adding atleast 5% padding and change value if you need more space

[image]