# How to set background of radio button dynamically created?

Tags: java, android-studio, radio-button

I want to achieve something like this:

[image: Here is the result image I want]

Where I can create a radio button dynamically and set its background programmatically. Please help me in this.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48155347/change-background-for-radio-button-programatically) ?

Comment: but I'm creating radio buttons programmatically.

Comment: There are several articles on creating buttons dynamically (like [this](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2013/05/09/dynamically-adding-custom-radio-buttons)), and the other link I provided gives you the methods to change the colour/background. Unless I am missing something you'd only need to combine the two together.