# to check the combination of pressed buttons 

Tags: android

I have 4 buttons (a1, a2, b1, b2). They can combinate: a1-b1; a1-b2; a2-b1; a2-b2.It means that "a1" and "a2" cann't be chosen together. So after clicking "a1" I need to block "a2".And depends on what 2 buttons were pressed, it will be differenet actions.I tried something like this

```
if(a1.isPressed()|| b1.isPressed()){
a2.setClickable(false);
b2.setClickable(false);}
```

but it didn't work.

## Update:

I tried to add boolean variable a1Boolean = false;
    boolean a2Boolean = false;
And after each click `a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            a1Boolean = true;`
```

And then to check in the method

`private boolean geta1_b1() {
        if (a1Boolean || b1Boolean) {
            a2.setClickable(false);
            b2.setClickable(false);
            }
        return true;
    }`

but when I call this method before all these clicks, of corse, it didn't work, because I didn't press any buttons yet. Any ideas how to find a right decision?

Answer (score 1):

Use `else if` statements. That is your best bet for something like this imo.

```
if(a1.isPressed()){
        a2.setClickable(false);
    }else if(b1.isPressed()){
        b2.setClickable(false)
    }
```

Make sure that you clear the state when appropriate.

Comment: it doesn't help. Even if I write if(a1.isPressed()){
        a2.setClickable(false);
    }  i can click "a2"

Comment: Did you try invalidating the view?

Comment: When should I invalidating the view?

Comment: if(a1.isPressed()){
   a2.setEnabled(false);
   a2.invalidate();}   still doesn't work:((

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [RadioGroups](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)?

Comment: Because it will be image inside the button. so, i cann't use radiobutton

Comment: You should consider using radio buttons for 2 reasons : 1) it would be easier to code, 2) it will be easier for users to recognize that the choices provided by your buttons are mutually exclusive. If you need image inside your buttons, you could consider designing custom radio buttons as proposed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576507/is-it-possible-to-change-the-radio-button-icon-in-an-android-radio-button-group

Answer (score 1):

you may try RadioGroup and [RadioButton](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#RadioButtons) and check which one is selected.

Comment: something like this? private boolean geta1_b1() {
  if (a1.isChecked()==true || b1.isChecked()==true) {
   a2.setClickable(false);
   b2.setClickable(false);
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

Answer (score 1):

you may invisible button like:

if(a1.isPressed()){
        a2.setVisibility(false);
    }else if(b1.isPressed()){
        b2.setVisibility(false)
    }

Comment: firstly, setVisibility couldn't be false, because "public void setVisibility (int visibility) 
Since: API Level 1 
Set the enabled state of this view.
" And even I write a2.setVisibility(View.GONE); - it doesn't work