# How to create a toggle button with 3 options...?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to create a toggle button with 3 options.
I don't want to use radio button or check box.

I want to create like this....

[image: toggle button]

How to create this...?

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: You can use RadioButton. It is duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576507/is-it-possible-to-change-the-radio-button-icon-in-an-android-radio-button-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the artwork for the left/middle/right buttons and create three separate buttons next to each other in a horizontal linear layout

Then in code get all three references to the buttons. When a button is clicked set a boolean e.g _button1Clicked = true (or use an array?) and set the image to a downstate, check the other buttons, set their images to upstate and reset their booleans to false!

Easy!