# How can I change the circle picture of a radio button in both cases checked and unchecked?

Tags: android

I want to customize the radio buttons so instead of being like this "empty circle in case unchecked and green on in case checked"
[image]

I want to make the picture in case it's unchecked like this
[image]

and in case it's checked like this [image]

How can I achieve that by xml or java??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [state list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) to define different drawables for different Button states.

Here is an example: [Is it possible to change the radio button icon in an android radio button group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576507/is-it-possible-to-change-the-radio-button-icon-in-an-android-radio-button-group)

Answer (score 0):

Use state list drawables. There's a tutorial on them [here](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/55).