# change just the android button color when selected in a spinner

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I currently have spinners with radio buttons that turn green when selected and I would like to have them be blue instead.  Can I do this without to much trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the only way would be to create your custom radio buttons. Won't be very difficult to implement. For that you will need to define the style in res/styles.xml and an xml for the radio buttons. In this xml file you can specify the drawables for selected state, un-selected state etc.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576507/is-it-possible-to-change-the-radio-button-icon-in-an-android-radio-button-group) answer out, it explains in detail what to do. Also [here's](http://blog.devminded.com/posts/custom-android-radiobutton) a tutorial on the same.

Hope this helps.