# Custom RadioButton not showing text

Tags: android, radio-button, android-widget

I have implemented the CustomRadioButton from [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576507/is-it-possible-to-change-the-radio-button-icon-in-an-android-radio-button-group).

Here, theme is implemented for to set the CustomRadioButton and then that theme is added to the activity.

I have done most of the steps and it works nice. But I want to add text on that radioButton then it's not possible?

Why am I not able to set the text for the RadioButton?

Comment: are you using the xml tag `android:text="text"`?

Comment: I have ues it but still not getting text.

Comment: I have Done same thing as explain in the link. There is no any extra code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be your width or color.  Does your radiobutton look like this?

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/type_pounds"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pounds"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```