# Android RadioButton dynamic icon change

Tags: android, image, radio-button

I'm doing a multiple choice quiz app. It has 4 `radio buttons`. What I want to have is have 3 icons -> No answer yet, right answer, wrong answer. So before any choice is clicked, all are non-answer, when an answer is clicked, if it is right, it light up green, if wrong - light up red. Is it possible to do with radio buttons? Or do I have to find another way out? Like using an `ImageView`?

Comment: For my point of view Yes it's possible to do that with radio button. You have to customize radio Button styles and put it in you app..

Comment: But you can only have Checked and notChecked states, so only two images. The onPressed states cannot be set, only executed.

Comment: Check my answer. I hop its helpful to you.

Comment: @Alexey can you post some code so that i can know it more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576507/is-it-possible-to-change-the-radio-button-icon-in-an-android-radio-button-group) Answer.

But u want verification for selected answer. I recognized to u that..Use ImageButton with TextView in your xml file Instead Of RadioButton.Initially Set notChecked image as background of ImageButtons .when User click on Any of your ImageButton. U can verify it On its OnClick event that is it r8 answer or not and then u can set Checked image(red/green) as background image of selected ImageButton.

Comment: Same thing, it only has two static states - Checked and notChecked. I can't make it hold in the onPressed state.

Answer (score 0):

Create one XML in "drawable" folder "radio.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_off" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: And 3rd state? I only see images for 2