# Rating Bar widget Java

Tags: java, gtk3, ratingbar

Do you a widget or a way to have a rating bar in java like android ? I'm using gtk3. I can create a radiobutton group which is quite similar but not the same visualy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the image of radiobutton with drawables.

[Possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576507/is-it-possible-to-change-the-radio-button-icon-in-an-android-radio-button-group)