# Android extend radioButton change color of its circle

Tags: android, android-custom-view, extends

I created a custom class that extends RadioButton .

my accent color is orange .But after that I used extended radioButton class , it will be black !!

How can I extends radioButton without changing it`s circle color?

Comment: Why can't you change it directly? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7620112/2649012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use `AppCompatRadioButton`. [Check this](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) for more details about  material design.

Comment: YES . I useed AppCompatRadioButton . And my problem solved