# Android RadioButtons Appearing Too Light

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have created a voting application and noticed that my RadioButtons are extremely light, I am barely able to see the circle associated with the RadioButton. I would like to darken, or bold, the RadioButtons (programmatically) if possible.

I programmatically add my RadioButtons:

```
public void addRadioButtonsWithFirebaseAnswers(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, int numberOfAnswers) {
    mPollAnswerArrayList = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAnswers; i++) {
        Log.e("Number of Answers", "The number of answers is " + numberOfAnswers);
        mPollAnswerArrayList.add(i, new RadioButton(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i).setId(i);
        String firebaseChild = String.valueOf(i + 1);
        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i).setText(dataSnapshot.child(POLL_ANSWERS_LABEL).child(firebaseChild).child("Answer").getValue().toString());
        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.radio_button_answer_text_size));
        mParams.setMargins((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.radio_question_margin_left), 0, 0, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.radio_question_margin_bottom));

        mPollQuestionRadioGroup.addView(mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i), mParams);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I found the same with some icons... until now doesn't know how to proceed. Plus one for your quest.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use custom radio buttons or consider changing the background of the activity.

Check this two topics:

[Is it possible to change the radio button icon in an android radio button group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576507/is-it-possible-to-change-the-radio-button-icon-in-an-android-radio-button-group)

[Adding custom radio buttons in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android)

Comment: Do you know why it is appearing light? I simply want to darken / bold it and am unsure why it is appearing light in the first place...