# Change Layout_Height of radio button thorught code

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, radio-button, android-custom-view

I have set the Layout_height of radio button to 0dp and i want to change that programmatically to wrap content when the button is pressed.

```
 r1 = (RadioButton) d.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                r2 = (RadioButton) d.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                r3 = (RadioButton) d.findViewById(R.id.textView15);

                //set up button
                Button button = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button2);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                Button button2 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button8);
                button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        r1.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 20));
                      // Tried this but it's not working


                    }
                });
```

Here is my xml code

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="500dp">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Industry"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Entertainment" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Garments"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Information Technology"
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

i don't know why it's not working, Thanks in advance !

Comment: Post your xml code

Comment: @kgandroid Done, re-check please.

Comment: Have you tried setLayoutParams with LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 20)

Comment: @maphongba008 just did. still no change :|

Comment: @shahtajkhalid I tested your code and it worked. Just replace FrameLayout by LinearLayout. If it still not work, you can hide the radio and onClick, you should show it (instead of set height)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot change the height and width of radio button as radio button is a built in control and is fixed.

If you want to change it then you have to define your own style for radio button.Find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576507/is-it-possible-to-change-the-radio-button-icon-in-an-android-radio-button-group).

Comment: No i want to change the Layout_height to wrap content not to any particular value or just height.